# Registered Mark does not appear when using @Page.Title!

Tags: html, syntax, razor, hex, webmatrix

I am using WebMatrix (I'm like, addicted to it), for a new site (well, it's just a new version of an existing site) and I have this:

_SiteLayout.cshtml:

```
@{
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>@Page.Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>@RenderBody()</body>
   </html>
}
```

and...

Default.cshtml:

```
@{
   Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
   Page.Title = "SexyDomainManager&reg;";
}
<p>Etc</p>
```

Which should make the title of the page look like this:

SexyDomainManager®

However, it doesn't. Instead, you can actually see `&reg;` in the title. This only happens when I use `@Page.Title`. Why? And how do I fix this?

Comment: On a side note: After clicking on the WebMatrix tag to the right, it looks like I'm dominating the list of WebMatrix-based questions. Not so sure if that's a good thing. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know "WebMatrix", but it obviously HTML encodes the values before including them in the output, so that the developer (you) doesn't need to, which is correct behavior for a web framework.

So if you what the title to contain "®" then write "®":

```
Page.Title = "SexyDomainManager®";
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess I can get used to pressing Ctrl+Alt+R to get ®. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Razor will automatically encode the HTML for you (which is why you don't see the symbol).

You could either put the symbol directly into your string or use the [Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method to return the raw string:

```
<title>@Html.Raw(Page.Title)</title>
```